# When creating new Thread ,how to pass a method which have Text Boxes as parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, textbox

When creating new `Thread` ,how to pass a method   which have `TextBoxes` as parameters??

```
private void waits(TextBox t1 ,TextBox t2)
{
    t1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    t2.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

Thread n1=new Thread(waits)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to do this. Most .NET UI frameworks do not allow you to modify a control, like a textbox from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass two parameters to a thread proc? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18815486/56778

Answer (score 0):

Use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

```
private void waits(TextBox t1 ,TextBox t2)
{
    t1.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
        t1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    });
    t2.Invoke(new Action(()=>
        t2.BackColor =  Color.Red;
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this makes any sense? Passing control to worker thread and back again to UI thread. I know if we do it in worker thread you'll get exception. but this doesn't makes any sense

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Does this make any sense? I don't know, but if the OP want to update a control from another Thread this is (one) of the way, know if you ask 'why do that?', no idea.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answers the question. pls read the question again. BTW two invoke calls are not required here, once you update the answer I'll remove my downvote

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, you are absolutely right, i didn't understand what OP asks, thanks.

Comment: Invoke() is dangerous, it is apt to cause deadlock.  And expensive.  You only need it when you need its return value, certainly not the case here.  Use BeginInvoke() instead.