# c# two object in class dont work thread

Tags: multithreading

I have a construct like this:

```
private readonly List<Thread> thr = new List<Thread>();
```

In a class i have a method with one parameter that i want to call threaded.

```
    public void testthr(object xxx)
    {
     ......
    }
```

on button click i start a thread

```
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < textBox8.Lines.Length; i++)
        {

            var thr1 = new Thread(testthr);
            thr1.Start(textBox8.Lines[i].Trim());

            thr.Add(threadz);

        }
```

How to make a thread with more than one parameter? Like:

```
    public void testthr(object xxx, string yyy)
    {
     ......
    }
```

this class in thread start ?

Comment: This question is really hard to understand. Please format your code samples properly, and tell us what errors, if any, you're getting from the code you tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/c-sharp-threadstart-with-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple values to a thread proc, you need to create an object to contain them. There are several ways to do that. The easiest is probably to use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx):

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < textBox8.Lines.Length; i++)
{

    var thr1 = new Thread(testthr);
    var data = new Tuple<string, string>(textBox8.Lines[i].Trim(), "hello");
    thr1.Start(data);

    thr.Add(thr1);

}

public void testthr(object state)
{
    var data = (Tuple<string,string>)state;
    var item1 = data.Item1;
    var item2 = data.Item2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for Jim Mischel its replay ok. how to this tuple starting semaphore thread ?